# Animating Views while using DataBinding in Android

Tags: android, animation, data-binding

I have started using DataBinding in one of my projects and have been facing problems with Managing the views and Animations. I am using DataBinding in my application and also using BindingAdapters to animate views when a certain boolean gets set. I have used a similar approach described in [this post](http://willowtreeapps.com/blog/animating-android-binding-transitions/).

In the animation I am trying to achieve using DataBinding, I have a searchbar in the middle of the screen and a list below it. When the user clicks on the searchBar, it animates to Top of the screen and the list scrolls to the bottom of the screen. (splitting a the center type animation)

I have certain boolean in my model, which gets set to true when the searchButton gets clicked and the BindingAdapter which listens in on that change in boolean, animates the view. I can get the view that needs to be animated but the amount by which the view animates depends on the size of another view, which is not being passed in the BindingAdapter. Is there a way to pass in multiple views in the BindingAdapter? My second question is, Since the searchbar and the list both animate on change of the same value, but how do I ensure that they animate simultaneously. If I were using 2 objectAnimators, I could use AnimatorSet and ensure synchronization, but how do I do this with DataBinding?

```
public class AnimHelper {

@BindingAdapter({"animatev1", "app:model"})
public static void Animate1(View view, boolean b, final Model model) {
    if (b) {
        ObjectAnimator a = ObjectAnimator
                .ofFloat(view, View.TRANSLATION_Y, -view.getHeight())
                .setDuration(2000);
        a.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                model.setAnim2(true);
            }
        });

        a.start();
    }
}

@BindingAdapter({"animatev2", "app:model"})
public static void Animate2(View view, boolean anim, final Model model) {
    if (anim) {
        ObjectAnimator a = ObjectAnimator
                .ofFloat(view, View.TRANSLATION_Y, view.getHeight())
                .setDuration(2000);
        a.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            }
        });

        a.start();
    }
}
}
```

the xml file is as follows:

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<data>

    <variable
        name="searchviewmodel"
        type="com.example.mvvmvariableupdatinginanimend.ViewModel" />
</data>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:animatev1="@{searchviewmodel.model.anim1}"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/search_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="202dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
                android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="Search Button1..."
               android:onClick="@{searchviewmodel.playSearchAnimation}"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrl_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:animatev1="@{searchviewmodel.model.anim1}"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In the above code on Click of searchBar, I am setting anim1 to true and the BindingAdapter written before does the animation of AppbarLayout and NestedScrollView on listening for changes in anim1. This seems to work as expected, but I want to account for the height of the Statusbar and searchButton in my animation, which is not happening currently, as I am not getting those views in my Animate1 function in AnimHelper.

Comment: post your code then

Comment: Posted the basic code, let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to pass other views as values in binding expressions.

```
<TextView ...
    app:animatev1="@{...}"
    app:otherView="@{myOtherView}"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/myOtherView" .../>
```

Your binding adapter can then take both parameters:

```
@BindingAdapter({"animatev1", "otherView"})
public static void animateV1(View view, boolean b, View otherView) {
    //...
}
```

As for your second question, I don't think you should have to worry about the synchronization. They should start animations at the same time.

There's no great way to use an AnimatorSet on two different views with data binding. You can do it by passing one View to the other's binding adapter and animating them both in the same binding adapter. But that's not a great option. It is better to just animate them separately in different binding adapters and count on the framework to do the right thing.

Comment: This answers my question. However, just adding on, the view ids are required to be camelCase and not seperated by underscore ( _ ), otherwise you get error "Identifiers must be user defined types from the xml file. my_other_view is missing it"

Comment: Yes, Data Binding changes names to camel case from underscores, just like file names.